# node-config cannot parse config SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to use [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) in my Node.js project.

Unfortunately I keep receiving an error when node-config tries to parse my JSON.

Here's the JSON throwing the error (actual data replaced with placeholder data)

```
{
    "Winston": {
        "Mail": {
            "to": "abc@test.com",
            "from": "errors@test.com",
            "host": "localhost"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error that I'm receiving:

> Error: Cannot parse config file: '../config/default.json' SyntaxError:Unexpected token ∩╗┐

I can't see where the syntax is incorrect but any help is appreciated.

Comment: look at the file with a hexeditor. you may have some unprintable garbage that's causing the json to become invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b), that did the trick.

I actually recreated the file in a different editor and that cleared up all of the issues.

The original .json file that I posted was created using the .json template  in VS2013 with [Node Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/node-js-vs) installed. Once I recreated the file using [Atom.io](http://atom.io) and relaunched my node app everything worked perfectly.

Thanks again for the help [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b).

Comment: I've had the same issue and looked into it. Apparently Visual Studio creates a Unicode file with a Byte Order Mark (BOM); my suspicion is node-config coughs on this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark